# Add individual EventHandler with array of Picturebox

Tags: c#, arrays, components, picturebox

I am initializing an array of `PictureBox`. The matter is, I cannot add individual `EventHandler` with each. I have this code in a for loop:

```
picBoxs[i] = new PictureBox();
picBoxs[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
picBoxs[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
picBoxs[i].Size = new Size(104, 104);
picBoxs[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
picBoxs[i].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
//this.picBoxs[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.picBoxs_Click); //Single EventHandler for all PictureBox(s)
this.picBoxs[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.picBoxs[i]_Click); //Generates error
```

I want `picBoxs1_Click()`, `picBoxs2_Click()`, `picBoxs3_Click()` ...(and so on). Because I need `EventHandler` for each `PictureBox`. I can make general `EventHandler`, `picBox_Click()` without any problem, but doing this I get a method for every `PictureBox`, I cannot do different stuffs after clicking different `PictureBox`. Any idea will greatly be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

**Edit:**
I want, when I click on a PictureBox, a message box will appear telling me an index of a 2D array. Say my picturebox(s) are arranged like this:

picBox0   picBox1  picBox2

picBox3   picBox4   picBox5

after clicking picBox2: MessageBox will say "[0][2]", same as clicking picBox4: MessageBox will say "[1][1]" and so on...

Comment: "Generates error" is very vague, and we've no idea which method you're trying to use. Please give more complete code. See http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Please read the edit(bellow the code) now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single event handler, like this:

```
this.picBoxs[i].Click += picBoxs_Click;
```

And within that event handler you can look up information about your picturebox:

```
void picBoxs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var box = sender as PictureBox;
    int i = Array.IndexOf(picBoxs, box);

    int columnCount = 3;
    int row = i / columnCount;
    int col = i % columnCount;

    Messagebox.Show(string.Format("[{0}][{1}]", row, col));       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without getting to complicated here this would be a simple soloution for you

First, declare a global const with the size of each box

```
const int BOX_SIZE = 128;
```

Then Create all those Boxes

```
this.picBoxs[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(Boxes_Click);
picBoxs[i].Location = new Point(x*BOX_SIZE, y*BOX_SIZE);
picBoxs[i].Size = new Size(BOX_SIZE,BOX_SIZE);
```

Finally the eventhandler:

```
void Boxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox theBox = sender as PictureBox;
    if(theBox != null)
    {

         MessageBox.Show("Box was clicked, x: {0} y:{1}", 
                         theBox.Location.X / BOX_SIZE, 
                         theBox.Location.Y / BOX_SIZE);
    } 
}
```

If this doesnt suit you, create a class that derives PictureBox and add a Property called Coordinates or something in which you then store the Coordinates of the Box.

```
class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    public Point Coordinates { get; set;}
}
```

Then:

```
int size_w = 128;
int size_h = 128;
```

...

```
MyPictureBox[] picBoxs = new MyPictureBox[1000];
```

...

```
picBoxs[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(Boxes_Click);
picBoxs[i].Coordinates = new Point(x,y);
picBoxs[i].Position = new Point(x * size_w, y*size_h);
picBoxs[i].Size = new Size(size_w, size_h);
```

...

```
void Boxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyPictureBox theBox = sender as MyPictureBox;
    if(theBox != null)
    {

     MessageBox.Show("Box was clicked, x: {0} y:{1}", 
                     theBox.Coordinates.X, 
                     theBox.Coordinates.Y);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know how many PictureBox will be there. It can be 5, can be 500 :(

Comment: So and you need to do 500 different things with them or what?

Comment: You might just tell us what you want to actually achieve.

Comment: np. Please consider @Joel Coehororn 's soloution aswell. Its way easier.